# How to create 2D slice plots from 3D data in R ?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, 2d, rgl

Here is the R code for my 3d Plot... I want to generate 2d slices of this 3d plot. I am using package rgl in R.

```
   library(rgl)

    > ncv1
             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 0.0087173253  0.0015347787  0.0007591226
[2,] 0.0015347787  0.0066770936 -0.0001649119
[3,] 0.0007591226 -0.0001649119  0.0011324989

> ncv2
             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 0.0080515223  0.0012391863  0.0006745652
[2,] 0.0012391863  0.0064364687 -0.0001695962
[3,] 0.0006745652 -0.0001695962  0.0011687981

> ntruemean
[1] 4.775067 5.596896 1.142223

> open3d()
wgl 
 10 

plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv2,ntruemean),col="red",type='shade',xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2),zlim=c(-2,2))

plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv1,ntruemean),col="blue",type='wire',add=TRUE,xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2),zlim=c(-2,2))

rgl.postscript("persp3dd1.eps","eps")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `clipplanes3d`?

Comment: I am able to slice the graph however is there any way we can slice it right in the center . So we only see red inside and blue net outslide ? I am having trouble finding the plane which goes through the center. Here is the code                 a<- 1
b<-1
c<-1
d<-0

open3d()
plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv2,ntruemean),col="red",type='shade',xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2),zlim=c(-2,2))

plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv1,ntruemean),col="blue",type='wire',add=TRUE,xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2),zlim=c(-2,2))
useSubscene3d(ids["clipregion"])
rgl.clipplanes(a, b, c, d)
rgl.postscript("persp3dd1.eps","eps")

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it pretty easily in any plane you like.  You just need to figure out the coefficients of the equation of the plane in `a x + b y + c z + d = 0` format, which is a 1st year linear algebra problem.

I can't do that for you, because I don't know what ellipse you are intending to draw, or what you mean by "right in the center".  You use `ntruemean` as a variable name, but pass it as the `scale` parameter, which doesn't really make sense.  I suspect you meant to pass it as the `centre` parameter.

Assuming that's what you meant, this clips in the center:

```
library(rgl)
ncv2 <- diag(1:3) # not your values
ntruemean <- 4:6  # also not your values
plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv2, centre = ntruemean),
       col="red", type='shade')
plot3d(ellipse3d(ncv2*1.01, centre = ntruemean), col = "blue", type="wire", add = TRUE)
normal <- 7:9  # Choose your own normal!
clipplanes3d(normal, d = -sum(normal * ntruemean))
```

Comment: My ellipse has the center ntruemean <-c(4.775067 5.596896 1.142223) and  variance covariance matricies are ncv1 (blue) and ncv2(red).  I want to slice my graph in such a way that I should be able to see only red part inside for both the slices and blue part outside. Same as cutting the apple in the middle so we see white part inside for both slices and red part outside. I am sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Your code didn't use `ntruemean` as the center, it used it as the scale.  The difference between an ellipsoid in `rgl` and an apple is that `rgl` can only draw the surface.  When you slice an apple you see what is below the surface.  To draw that, `rgl` would need to support "3D textures", and it doesn't.